# .NET MAUI TabBar Login/Logout Issue

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, navigation, maui

i am having an issue whereby when a user navigates to the Settings Tab and clicks the logout option this then navigates the user back to the login screen but when the user logs back in the Tab Bar is still set to the settings screen. How do i stop this happening and default it back to the Dashboard on Login

Process

1. User Login (Tab Selected: Dashboard)
2. User Goes to Settings Tab (Tab Selected: Settings)
3. Logout Function
4. User Login (Tab Selected: Settings)

**AppShell.Xaml**

```
 <TabBar Route="Login">
        <ShellContent
            x:Name="ViewShell"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AutoLoginView}"
            Route="AutoLoginView" />
    </TabBar>

    <TabBar Route="BottomNavigationMenu">

        <ShellContent
            Title="Home"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardView}"
            Icon="home.svg" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Scan"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:RewardScanView}"
            Icon="scan.svg" />
        <ShellContent
            Title="Settings"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsView}"
            Icon="settings.svg" />
    </TabBar>
```

**Logout Functionality (SettingsViewModel)**

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Login");
```

**Login Functionality (LoginViewModel)**

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//BottomNavigationMenu");
```

Comment: You could put your ```LoginPage``` (AutoLoginView) outside the shell hierarchy and set the ```MainPage = new AutoLoginView();``` in App.xaml.cs. When you login successfully and navigate to the ```BottomNavigationMenu```, just use ```Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add Route to the `DashboardView` in the AppShell.xaml file and then rewrite the `GoToAsync` in the LoginViewModel, like the following code:

AppShell.xaml:

```
<ShellContent
    Route = "Dashboard"
    Title = "Home"
    ContentTemplate = "{DataTemplate local:DaashboardView}"
    Icon = "home.svg" />
```

LoginViewModel:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//dashboard");
```

Comment: About the using of `route`, you can refer to the document of [Register routes in shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#routes)